# Elide text of QPushButton in Qt Symbian C++

Tags: c++, qt, symbian

How to elide the text of a `QPushButton` ?

Comment: Elide can mean, just truncate (cut-off) or add ellipsis (normally 3 trailing dots ... to the text). Which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Qt example for an elided label I came up with the following solution. It is mostly based on the Qt example, I have only simplified it according to my requirements:

HEADER:

```
/**
 * Push button with elided text
 * \remark based on http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-elidedlabel-example.html
 */
class CElidedPushButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text WRITE setText)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool isElided READ isElided)

public:
    //! Constructor
    explicit CElidedPushButton(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    //! Constructor
    explicit CElidedPushButton(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    //! Text
    void setText(const QString &text);

    //! Text
    const QString &text() const { return m_content; }

    //! Elided?
    bool isElided() const { return m_elided; }

protected:
    //! \copydoc QPushButton::paintEvent
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;

private:
    bool m_elided = false;
    QString m_content;
};
```

CPP:

```
CElidedPushButton::CElidedPushButton(QWidget *parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{ }

CElidedPushButton::CElidedPushButton(const QString &text, QWidget *parent)
    : QPushButton(parent), m_elided(false), m_content(text)
{
    this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
}

void CElidedPushButton::setText(const QString &newText)
{
    m_content = newText;
    this->update();
}

void CElidedPushButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    const QFontMetrics fontMetrics = painter.fontMetrics();
    const int usableWidth = qRound(0.9 * this->width());

    const QString elidedText = fontMetrics.elidedText(m_content, Qt::ElideRight, usableWidth);
    m_elided = (elidedText != m_content);
    QPushButton::setText(elidedText);
    QPushButton::paintEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: `setText()` will change the buttons text. Proper way is to paint the text as elided but don't change the actual text.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean add Ellipsis. Next time google better:
[ElidedButton Class Reference](http://opticks.org/docs/sdk/4.8.0/d2/d7e/classElidedButton.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
YourPushButton->setText("");
```

Comment: I want elide means truncate text after some length, so that big text is visible on my button

Comment: You requirement is not clear. Is it QPushButton or some other widget?? You can set text size by setting its stylesheet.